# How to store every word of one input field in a new string

Tags: java, android, string, input

I can get the input into one string. Like that:

```
input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input1);
text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);

String value = input.getText().toString();
text.setText(value);
```

But how can I get the text of the input and store each word in a single variable?
I searched very long but nothing worked.

Comment: Split the entire string that you already have?

Comment: You can split the string into a String array. Convert the string to upper or lower case (for uniformity). Be sure to remove every punctuation chars. Use space as the separator character.

Comment: The question is not clear. What do you want to split? Did you mean every character of String in to array?

Comment: @Prince I have a String like "I am human"; I want to split the string into new Strings for each word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`toCharArray()`** method of String class

```
char[] values = value.toCharArray();
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
String value = "Hello";
char[] values = value.toCharArray();

for(char c: values){
    System.out.println(" "+ c);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
H
e
l
l
o
```

### FOR SPLITTING INTO STRING

Use **`split(String regex)`** method

**EXAMPLE**

```
String value = "Hello My Friends";
    String[] values = value.split(" ");

    for(String c: values){
        System.out.println(" "+ c);
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Hello
My
Friends
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice example. But I want it like this: MyString = "Hello my friends"; And now I want to have three Strings for example with the three words. String1 = "Hello"; String2 = "my"; String3 = "friends";

Comment: Thank you I understand but I want to store each of the three words (Hello) (My) (Friends) into a new String. Do you know how I could make that?

Comment: dear here every word is in a new String : String[0] ,String[2] and String[2]

Comment: Its saved in String[] so you can place it in other Activity by passing values as String[ArrayIndex]. I hope i m not getting u wrong.

Comment: Ohh sorry man I'm so stupid. It works now. I didn't get what String[] values = value.split(" "); does. Very very thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

String[] variables = value.split(" ");

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

use string builder to get all data.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(keyvalue);
txtView.setText(sb);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split on `white space`:

```
String[] words = value.split(" ");
```

And then you can access different words using `words[0]`, `words[1]` and like so.

You can perform operations or checks on different words like:

`words[0].equals(...);`

`words[1].contains(...);`

`words[2].substring(...);`

and like so.

You can also print it out using `for each` like:

```
for(String word : words){

    // Whatever you want
    System.out.println(word.toString());
}
```

Comment: Okay that sounds very well. I tried it but I don't understand how to access different words.. Can you show me an example maybe?

Comment: Each `String` will be stored separately in `words[]` array and you can later access each word as `words[0]`, `words[1]`, and so on till `words[words.length-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
 StringBuffer liked_Users = new StringBuffer();
 for(int j =0 ;j<50;j++)
 {      
     liked_Users.append("Your Text goes here : "+j);
 }
 Log.d("TAG","String is : "+liked_Users.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you

```
 import java.util.Scanner;


    public class Stri {

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            Scanner S=new Scanner(System.in);
            int i = 0;
            //String s=S.nextLine();
            String s="I am boopathi";
            String[] parts = s.split(" ");
            for(i=0;i<parts.length;i++)
            {
                System.out.println(parts[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```